# Adjust an iframes height so its the size of the viewport

Tags: javascript, iframe

my page has a div on the top of 100px height and an iframe beneath it. I want the iframe to fill teh rest of the page viewport i.e that the iframe's height should adjust as the browser window adjusts so we don't see two scroll bars  - I just want that the scrollbar should be visible in the iframe and not in the browsers own viewport.

Comment: For browsers other than IE6-7 you can do this with plain CSS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303729/iframe-100-height-inside-body-with-padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should wrap the iframe in a div for which you make a class in CSS that has `overflow:scroll;`, `height:100%;` and `margin-top:100px;`
The height makes you fill the whole page, the margin-top clears room for your top div and the overflow ensures you get scrollbars around your iframe. You might need to play a little with the height.

As far as I know it is not possible to actually change the iframe's height, since you import it from another page.

Hope I could help a bit.