# How do I have a fixed height header with a content div that takes up 100% of the remaining space?

Tags: css, height, html

Before I start, I know there are a lot of questions on here related to this, but I feel like the answers are seriously lacking.  They at least aren't making sense to me, or they don't accomplish what I want.  If you know of question with a solid solution that this duplicates, I simply missed it; I will delete this one.

If I have the following HTML...

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

How, in simple terms, can I make the header take up 50px of the view port's height and make the content portion fill the rest of the view port's height with no scrollbar?  Ideally this would work in IE6 and without tables.  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303729/iframe-100-height-inside-body-with-padding works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to work for me:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="height:60px; position:fixed; width:100%;"></div>
        <div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
            <p style="padding-top:60px;">hola</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you forget a link perhaps?

Comment: You would need to set `height: 100%` on both `html` and `body` to make this work in Standards Mode. And of course IE6 doesn't do `fixed`.

Comment: How would you position something vertically central in the p? The p has no set height...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need but it will result in #content taking up all the viewport and #header is contained within that, then any content you wanted to put in #content will appear after header.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #header {
      height: 50px;
      background: green;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #content {
      background: blue;
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
      height: auto !important;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">I am the header</div>
    <p>first bit of content</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

height:auto !important; height:100%; bit is for IE 6, you'd ideally do than in a style sheet directed at IE 6 only using IE condition comments.